# Google maps missing tile handling

Tags: javascript, google-maps, http-status-code-404, tiles

Please advise how can I show special tile instead of missing tiles on my ImageMapType?

My map has a lot of missing tiles and now it reports about 404 error for every tile. I'd like to handle it and show just black tile.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Mike Williams describes one method in his v2 tutorial on [custom maps](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/custommap.htm).

Comment: unfortunately it does not help I cannot say at that moment which tiles exist

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htaccess to redirect non-existing tiles to an "empty" tile:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ your_path_to empty_tile/none.png [L]
```

Empty tile attached:

[image: 1x1 empty tile]